# Making values to perform addition in a single textbox

Tags: c#

I recently got stuck in my project as I have requirements that I need to fulfil, the need to perform addition in a single textbox. 
I've view the most similar posts and it gave a good idea of it, [Addition using a single TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649007/addition-using-a-single-textbox#).

Instead of int, I am required to use double like how it was done with int.

```
  private int i = 0;
private int[] a = new int[2];
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int b;
    if(Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out b))
    {
        a[i] = b;
        i++;
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Incorrect number");
    }


}

private void resultbutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = a[0] + a[1];
    MessageBox.Show("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

}

Instead, what code should I use to create a similar things for double?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your code, just do this :

```
private int i = 0;
private double[] a = new double[2];
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double b;
   if (Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out b))
   {
      a[i] = b;
      i++;
      textBox1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show(@"Incorrect number");
    }
}

private void resultbutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double sum = a[0] + a[1];
   MessageBox.Show("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

But you can try this for adding more than 2 doubles :

```
private double result = 0.0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double b;
   if (Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out b))
   {
          result += b,
          textBox1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show(@"Incorrect number");
    }
}

private void resultbutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Sum: " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double b = 0;
try{
    b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
} 
catch(e){
   // Error Handling
}
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.105)

Answer (score 0):

you can try use something like:

```
Double.Parse("1.2");
```

some examples here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx